# Spring JUnit Testing issue

Tags: spring, exception, junit, datasource

I have my AbstractResourceTest class as

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:betty/spring/dataSourceContextTest.xml", "classpath*:betty/spring/persistentContextTest.xml", "classpath*:betty/spring/applicationContextTest.xml" })
public class AbstractResourceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
     @Autowired
     protected HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
     protected long mpId, t1, t2, t3, t4, r1, r2, r3, r4, otuId, ofpId, ponId, teId, mp1, mp2, mp3, md1;
     protected int validationRuleCount;

     private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  and so on...
```

and dataSourceContextTest.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3386/betty_junit" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10"></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100"></property>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="10"></property>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"></property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true"></property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false"></property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="50"></property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30"></property>
</bean>
```

but when i run the test, i am getting below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'be.belgacom.rosy.betty.dbaccess.repositoryImpl.MeasurementRepositoryImplTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
... 26 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
... 28 more
```

my xmls are loaded at [src\test\resources\betty\spring]

can any one help? I verified mysql connection properties, they are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution, but since you are using spring 3, change this:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
```

to:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

or:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: According to this post http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?47289-Spring-2-5-Eclipse-reports-quot-JUnit4ClassRunner-cannot-be-resolved-quot

I have extended AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Comment: do you have a transaction manage defined in your XML somewhere?

Comment: exception stack strace clearly says that DataSource bean not found - it's either not created because of some  exception down the stack trace or not declared at all because some XML's not included or it's not declared at all :-)

Comment: is it dataSourceContextTest.xml or dataSourceContexTest.xml ?

Comment: are you using spring 2.5 or spring 3?

Comment: I have declared transaction in persistentContextTest.xml

http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?befd6666aef603c7#yXbOejqrUwQ3iKTz9EzzbJ10DL47vVt7WXlFwEHVL8M=

Comment: Spring 3. http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?c8b613cf727ff26d#VHe2fBSpnblhBoAxaR2kQpyv0BWiAAqphc+mZr9D1LQ=

Comment: @Nitin where is the datasource declared? in which file? this file must be either imported to your beans xml or added to contextconfiguration annotation

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, as per my post, it's declared in dataSourceContextTest.xml and the same thing is mentioned in Test class configuration

Comment: @Nitin then check that there no other exceptions down the log that prohibit the creation of datasource

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, sorry can you explain how do i trace that

Comment: @nitin i suppose there are another  exceptions besides that ones you have posted - maybe the console output is truncated by your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your beans in the config.xml file?

Comment: config.xml? where's that came from :)